# test method is failing 0% coverage is coming

Tags: apex, unit-test, failing-tests

Controller:

```
public class WizardClass 
{
      public Opportunity Oppo{get;set;}
      public List<Quote> quoteList{get;set;}
      public List<QuoteLineItem> quoteLineItemList{get;set;}
      public List<Quote> newQuoteList{get;set;}
      Pricebook2 standardPB;

    public WizardClass()
    {
        Oppo = new Opportunity();
        quoteList = new List<Quote>();
        quoteList.add(new quote());
        quoteLineItemList = new List<QuoteLineItem>();
        quoteLineItemList.add(new QuoteLineItem());
        }

    public void CreateQuote()
    {
        quoteList.add(new quote());
        }

    public void CreateQuoteLineItem()
    {
        quoteLineItemList.add(new QuoteLineItem());
        }

    public PageReference QuotePage()
    {
        return Page.OppoQuotes;
        }


    public PageReference Create()
    {
        //Pricebook2 pb = [Select id, name From Pricebook2 Where name ='Standard Edition'];
        standardPB = [select id from Pricebook2 where name='Standard' And IsActive=true limit 1];
        Oppo.Pricebook2Id = standardPB.Id;
        insert Oppo; 

        List<Quote> quoList = new List<Quote>();
        for(Quote q : quoteList)
        {
            Quote quo = new Quote();
            quo.OpportunityId = Oppo.id;
            quo.Pricebook2Id = standardPB.Id;
            quo.name = q.name;
            quoList.add(quo);
            }
       // q.OpportunityId = Oppo.id;
        insert quoList;
        newQuoteList = quoList;
        PageReference newPage = new PageReference('/apex/OppoQuoteLine');
        return newPage;
        }

     public PageReference QuoteLineItemPage()
     {
       // Map<String,Quote> mapping = new Map<String,Quote>([Select id, name, (Select id, name From QuoteLineItem) From Quote]);

      //  Pricebook2 pb = new Pricebook2(Name = 'Standard Price Book 2009', Description = 'Price Book 2009 Products', IsActive = true);
     //   insert pb;

        //PricebookEntry standardPrice = new PricebookEntry(Pricebook2Id = standardPB.Id, Product2Id = prod.Id, UnitPrice = 10000, IsActive = true, UseStandardPrice = false);
      //  insert standardPrice;
     //   PricebookEntry pbe = new PricebookEntry(Pricebook2Id = standardPB.Id, UnitPrice = 10000, IsActive = true, UseStandardPrice = false);
       // insert pbe;

      /*  Pricebook2 pb = new Pricebook2(Name = 'Standard Price Book 2009', Description = 'Price Book 2009 Products', IsActive = true );
        insert pb; 
        Product2 prod = new Product2(Name = 'SLA: Bronze', IsActive = true);
        insert prod;
        PricebookEntry pbe = new PricebookEntry(Pricebook2Id = pb.Id, Product2Id = prod.Id, UnitPrice = 1000, IsActive = true);
        insert pbe;*/



        /*Map<Id,Product2> mapProduct = new Map<Id,Product2>([Select id, name, Family, ProductCode From Product2]);
        for(Product2 pro : [Select id from Product2])

            PricebookEntry pbe = new PricebookEntry();
            pbe.Pricebook2Id = pb.Id;
            pbe.Product2Id = mapProduct.get(
            UnitPrice = 1000; 
            IsActive = true;
            insert pbe;*/

        List<QuoteLineItem> qliList = new List<QuoteLineItem>();
        for(Quote q : newQuoteList)
        {
            system.debug('newQuoteList'+newQuoteList);
            system.debug('newQuoteList'+q);
           for(quoteLineItem qli : quoteLineItemList)
           {
           // QuoteLineItem qliObj = new QuoteLineItem();
            qli .QuoteId= q.id;
            qli .PriceBookEntryId = setPriceBookEntry(standardPB.id,qli.Product2Id);
            system.debug('qliobj'+qli );
            qliList.add(qli );
            system.debug('qli'+qliList);
               }
            }      
        insert qliList;
        PageReference pg = new PageReference('/'+oppo.id);
        return pg;
        }           

         public ID setPriceBookEntry(ID stPBID, ID pid){

            PricebookEntry pbe = new PricebookEntry(Pricebook2Id = stPBID, 
                                                    Product2Id = pid, 
                                                    UnitPrice = 1000, 
                                                    IsActive = true);
            insert pbe;
             return pbe.id;
        }        

}
```

Test Class:

```
@isTest  
Private class WizardClassTest
{  
      static testMethod void unitTest()   
     {    
        Test.startTest() ; 

        PriceBook2 pb = new PriceBook2();
        pb.Name = 'New PriceBook';
        insert pb;

        Opportunity opp = new opportunity();  
        opp.Name = 'Roy';  
        opp.CloseDate = system.today();  
        opp.StageName = 'Prospecting' ;  
        opp.Pricebook2Id = pb.Id;
        //Insert opp;  

        List<Quote> quoteList = new List<Quote>();  
        Quote q = new Quote();  
        q.name = 'Joe';  
        q.opportunityId = opp.Id;  
        q.Pricebook2Id = pb.Id;
        quoteList.add(q);  

        Quote quo = new Quote();  
        quo.name = 'Monroe';  
        quo.opportunityId = opp.Id;
        q.Pricebook2Id = pb.Id;  
        quoteList.add(quo);  
        //insert quoteList; 

        Product2 pro = new Product2();
        pro.Name = 'Go Pro';

        insert pro;

        PriceBookEntry pbe = new PriceBookEntry(Pricebook2Id = pb.id, 
                                                    Product2Id = pro.Id, 
                                                    UnitPrice = 1000, 
                                                    IsActive = true);
        insert pbe;

        List<QuoteLineItem> qli = new List<QuoteLineItem>();
        QuoteLineItem ql = new QuoteLineItem();
        ql.QuoteId = q.id;
        ql.PriceBookEntryId = pbe.Id;
        qli.add(ql);

        WizardClass wc = new WizardClass();
        wc.oppo = opp;
        wc.quoteList = quoteList;
        wc.Create();
        wc.CreateQuote();
        wc.QuotePage();
        wc.quoteLineItemList = qli;
        wc.QuoteLineItemPage();


        //System.assertEquals(2,opp.quotes.size());  

        Test.stopTest();
    }  
 }
```

Method is failing 0% coverage is coming.I dont know whats happening..

Comment: We don't as well. Would you share with us more details about failure?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: STANDARD_PRICE_NOT_DEFINED, No standard price defined for this product: []

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008yveIAA

Answer (score 1):

You need to define standard price book like below code.

```
Pricebook2 standardPB = [select id from Pricebook2 where isStandard=true];

PriceBookEntry pbe = new PriceBookEntry(Pricebook2Id = standardPB.id, 
                                                Product2Id = pro.Id, 
                                                UnitPrice = 1000, 
                                                IsActive = true,   UseStandardPrice = false);
insert pbe;
```

Comment: why don't you just use `Test.getStandardPricebookId()`? Why re-inventing the wheel?

Comment: It worked..Thanx man...